# Generate data based on exponential distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to generate a dataset of 30 entries such between the range of (50-5000) such that it follows an increasing curve(log curve) i.e. increasing in the start and then stagnant in the end.

I came across the `from scipy.stats import expon` but I am not sure how to use the package in my scenario.

Can anyone help.

A possible output would look like `[300, 1000, 1500, 1800, 1900, ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to generate 30 random `x` values (uniformly). Then you get `log(x)`. Ideally, `log(x)` should be in range `[50, 5000)`. However, in such case you would need `e^50 <= x <= e^5000` (overflow!!). A possible solution is to generate random x values in `[min_x, max_x)`, get the logarithmic values and then scale them to the desired range `[50, 5000)`.

```
import numpy as np

min_y = 50
max_y = 5000
min_x = 1
# any number max_x can be chosen
# this number controls the shape of the logarithm, therefore the final distribution
max_x = 10

# generate (uniformly) and sort 30 random float x in [min_x, max_x)
x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(min_x, max_x, 30))
# get log(x), i.e. values in [log(min_x), log(max_x))
log_x = np.log(x)
# scale log(x) to the new range [min_y, max_y)
y = (max_y - min_y) * ((log_x - np.log(min_x)) / (np.log(max_x) - np.log(min_x))) + min_y
```

Comment: @Ricaardo Bucco Thank you for your answer, However the curve doesn't seem to look like that. I wanted to have a curve like :  https://www.google.com/search?q=log+curve&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSG856SG856&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAos7T28PlAhVEWX0KHdSyBNMQ_AUIEigB&biw=1440&bih=749&dpr=2#imgrc=U14JsVRLMGY_wM:

Comment: @user3759616 Try to adjust the parameter max_x (try with smaller and higher values, until you reach the result that fully satisfies you)